# Storing data from axios to use it later via util functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a simple axios GET call, which I would like to store for later use by some util functions. As this is a react app, could it be stored in memory (browser) or in a file in a dir?

```
const data = [];

const getData = (logName) => {
  if (logName === '') {
    alert('Please enter the name of your log!');
  } else {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://xxx-yyy-zzz/debugger/RTS/${logName}/logs`,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        alert('Successfully Imported');
        return data.push(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};

const askPrice = () => {
  return data.map((result) => result.request.requestContext.mpcBidRequest.askPrice);
};
```

This is what I currently have, previously `data` was just `import data from '../data/x.json';` But now I would like to call the request and replace `import data from '../data/x.json';` with the returned data from the GET response.

The function...

```
const askPrice = () => {
  return data.map((result) => result.request.requestContext.mpcBidRequest.askPrice);
};
```

Will be used later (after calling the API) to then map over the array of JSON objects to output the results to a UI. My app works perfectly well using `import data from '../data/x.json';` but now I want to get user input to generate the data.

Comment: You can import a function or promise that lets you get the data, but if it's async, the json won't be there when you import it.

Comment: Do you need `data` in a specific component or it must be accessible from a global state from many components? Do you want to fetch the data only once when the App loads or after a component loads or after a specific user action?

Comment: I would like to fetch the data after a user input fire a form and a button click. Then once the data is loaded...users will click buttons which will fire the util functions to get the relevant data from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to store what i need into a `let` and have tested things...everything works ok.

```
let data = [];

async function getData(filter, logName) {
  if (logName === '') {
    alert('Please enter the name of your log!');
  } else {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://xxx/debugger/${filter}/${logName}/logs`,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.length === 0) {
          console.log(res.data);
          alert('Your query returned empty JSON!');
        } else {
          console.log(res.data);
          data = res.data;
        }

        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```